# How to stop the timer once you end an exam?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to stop this timer when I end the exam, but before it reaches zero. Kindly help me out on scripts please. Thanks.

JavaScript code:

```
var cnt = 165*60; // 165 minutes (2 hours & 45 minutes) convert to seconds

function countdown() {
    if (cnt < 0) {
        document.f.c.value = "- : - - : - -" ;
    }
    else {
        hour = Math.floor(cnt / 3600);
        totalmin = Math.floor(cnt / 60);
        min = totalmin - (hour * 60);
        sec = cnt - (totalmin * 60);
        if (sec < 10) { sec = "0" + sec;}
        if (min < 10) {min = "0" + min;}
        if (hour < 10) {hour = "0" + hour;}
        document.f.c.value = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
        cnt--;
        _timer = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);
    }
}

var _timer = setTimeout("countdown()", 1000); // tick
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you meant that you want to end the timer *before* the countdown reaches 0.

First of all, you should use `setInterval` instead. It should work in all major browsers (including IE). It is just a slightly nicer way to express "I want this to happen every so often." According to the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/window.setInterval), it:

> Calls a function repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

Here's how you would use it:

```
var cnt = 165*60; // 165 minutes (2 hours & 45 minutes) convert to seconds
function countdown() {
  if (cnt < 0) {
   document.f.c.value = "- : - - : - -" ;
  }
  else {
   hour = Math.floor(cnt / 3600);
   totalmin = Math.floor(cnt / 60);
   min = totalmin - (hour * 60);
   sec = cnt - (totalmin * 60);
   if (sec < 10) {sec = "0" + sec;}
   if (min < 10) {min = "0" + min;}
   if (hour < 10) {hour = "0" + hour;}
   document.f.c.value = hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
   cnt--;

   if(cnt <= 0) { # Stops the timer when it reaches 0.
       clearInterval(_interval);
   }
  }
}
var _interval = setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

And somewhere in your page have a button that will stop the timer.

```
<input type="button" value="Done" onclick="clearInterval(_interval)">
```

Although to be honest, having a countdown timer freaks me out. I'd rather have a count-up timer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In your else part
check

```
if(current_time < total_time)
{
   //Set TimeOut
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet here is to use setInterval rather than setTimeout.

setInterval returns a handle to the interval.  clearInterval(handle) will cancel that interval.  Here's some pseudo to get you started:

```
var global_timer;

function countdown(){
    // do some countdown stuff

    if([we're done]) {
        window.clearInterval(global_timer);
    }
}

global_timer = window.setInterval("countdown()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code that you execute when user ends the exam, probably after button click, just add such line:

```
window.clearTimeout(_timer);
```

And the timer will stop ticking.